# True or false? This relation is an equivalence relation: $xRy \Leftrightarrow x \cdot y$ is even

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

> The following relation is defined on $\mathbb{N}^{+}$
>
> True or false? This relation is an equivalence relation: $xRy
> \Leftrightarrow x \cdot y$ is even

First, relation is equivalence relation if it have property: reflexive, symmetric, transitive.

$xRy
\Leftrightarrow x \cdot y$ is even $\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ }$ This says that when product is even, you have relation that satisfy all these property i.e. is equivalence relation, right?

Is allow I negate the relation and find counterexample?

Negation say: If product of $x,y$ is uneven, you don't get equivalence relation.

Let me make example, $x=y=1:$ $1 R 1 \Leftrightarrow 1$ is uneven

But $(1,1)$ is equivalence relation. Statement is false.

Is all good work or I do wrong?

Comment: Yes, one conterexample to reflexivity such as $1\not R1$ is enough to show that $R$ is not an equivalence relation. Additionally, $R$ fails to be transitive, for example $1R2$ and $2R3$, but $1\not R3$.

Comment: Pls no give me negative point!!

Comment: Exercise.  Shiw the relation is symmetric and not transtive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$R$ is a relation. A relation can either be True or False for a pair. So when we look at $1R1$ this state that $1*1$  is even, which is clearly false, just like you have stated.

As you say, an equivalence relation has to be reflexive i.e. for each positive integer x, $xRx$ should hold. But you have shown that $1R1$ does not hold, and thus $R$ is not reflexive and thus $R$ is not an equivalence relation.

Your proof is correct and good up to the English. It would also be nice to see that you recognize that you are contradicting the reflexivity.